# How to resize an image that has a gradient according to the current page height?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using an image as the background for my site. It has a black/white gradient, and is 1px wide.

The CSS:

```
background-image:url('../image/gradient.png');
```

which makes it repeat itself. The height of the image is 2000px.

Is it possible to change the height of the image dynamically, so it fits all page sizes: If the height of a page is less than 2000px, the height of the image should be smaller, if the height of the page is bigger, the image should be bigger.

Thanks in advance

I have tried various in-browser gradient techniques, and they dont seem to work the same on all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe am not getting the right context of your question, but this can be do it easily with somethin like

```
#SomeImg.src {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Resize this page to see it action: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageToBackgroundImage/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the height of the image is 2000px, this does not resize the height. height: 100% does not work either :/

Comment: I changed it to position: fixed and height: 100%, this seems to work fine. I will have to test it on another screen first.

Comment: yes, the code is just an example, but yes, with something like the code you wrote should work fine... cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I usually approach this problem in one of two ways.

If you can use CSS3, then use CSS gradients (I always find http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ a good choice to play about with gradients), you can then set this to be 100% height of the window.

If CSS3 isn't an option, i usually just pick a height, say 500px, and make a gradient for that. Then, since gradients typically go from colour A to colour B, just set the underlying background colour to match colour B and the gradient will work similarly on all monitors.

Assuming a gradient going from blue to black:

```
body {
    /* ensure body always fills viewport */
    min-height: 100%;

    /*gradient fades to black so set underlying BG to black*/
    background: url(/path/to/gradient.gif) repeat-x #000; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 you can use `background-size: cover` and there are some other techniques discussed [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/).

Answer (score 0):

You could create several images with varying heights and dynamically match the closest image size. If you do this you'd need to tie into the `window.resize` event to update the image if the user resizes the window.

```
window.onload = setBackgroundImage;
window.onresize = setBackgroundImage;

function setBackgroundImage() {
    var winH = 500;
    if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
        winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
    } else if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
        winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    } else if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
        winH = window.innerHeight;
    }

    if (winH > 400) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../image/gradient800px.png')";
    } else if (winH > 800) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../image/gradient1000px.png')";
    } else if (winH > 1000) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../image/gradient1500px.png')";
    } else if (winH > 1500) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../image/gradient2000px.png')";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('../image/gradient400px.png')";
    }
}
```

I don't think the solution is very pretty, but it should work.